# Is the GiffyGlyph's Darker Dungeons set of rules balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, house-rules

I came across the the [GiffyGlyph's Darker Dungeons](http://giffyglyph.com/darkerdungeons/) extension set of rules for D&D 5e and I find them fascinating. I like some of the concepts a lot and the fact you can pick and choose what to include.

I'm planning to switch from standard 5e to this set of rules to include conditions (thirst, hunger, fatigue), exhaustion, intelligence for initiative, slot based inventory and wounds and injuries.

I'd love to include them but I haven't been able to find any review or opinions online.

**Does anyone have any experience including them in an actual game?** Are these set of rule extensions balanced?

Comment: "Balanced" against what, exactly? It's hard to answer a question about balance without something to compare it to.

Comment: Analysis of 70+ pages looks like too broad task for Q&A format, especially given that 1) these rules are said to be modular so there probably is a myriad of combinations and 2) content you linked to is on external server without proper version control, so pdf may be replaced after answers are posted, may be removed etc. It is a "link only question" in my eyes and it suffers all of the issues that caused link only answers to be banned network-wide.

Comment: I agree it’s broad so I’ve remarked the part about experience with the set of rules. I want to know if they break the balance of the game or are ok. Maybe it IS too broad for the site though.

Comment: You can’t just say “balance.”  These rules are by their nature designed to make dungeoneering harder, so they are by definition not “balanced” with the core rules, that’s their point.  So probably you mean do they affect certain classes more than others?  Or do they make the game so challenging it’s not fun?  What really is it you want to know?

Comment: Yes, I was interested in knowing whether the rules would “break” the game. As in being abused or breaking the balance between classes or races. It is probably too broad though as mentioned above. I haven’t been able to find good reviews so I didn’t know what to make of them... given lack of feedback online I’ll probably resort to giving them a try, given the fact I like them

Comment: Note part of the reason for the question is: this set of rules is known/popular enough to have its own character sheet in roll20 so I figured it was somehow widely used and discussed.

Comment: @JorgeCórdoba: "this set of rules is known/popular enough to have its own character sheet in roll20" - To clarify, all this actually means is that a fan found it worth taking the effort to modify the character sheet accordingly. Most Roll20 sheets are fanmade.